# Filtering by query params in many to many relationship using drf

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(verbose_name="unique id", primary_key=True, max_length=256)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    published_date = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    average_rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    ratings_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    thumbnail = models.URLField(verbose_name="thumbnail url", null=True, blank=True, default=None)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=256)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='authors')
```

What i want to achieve is that i want to filter api queries by using query params like this:

> 127.0.0.1/books?author='something'

So my param is something in that case.

I want to filter by names of authors and check if there are books that have relationship with this authors. Also it is important that there could be more than just one param at the time like this:

> ?author='something1'&author='something2'

I have no idea how to achieve this. I'm trying with default filtering using get_queryset function in generic classes of DRF, but have no idea still.

Comment: Have you implemented a simpler filter such as `/books?title="I, Robot"`? If not, I suggest you do that first so you can understand basic filtering then build on that to implement filtering on a many-to-many field.

Answer (score 2):

The right way is to use django-filter:
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/install.html

Like this:

```
class BookFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['authors']

class BookViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = BookFilterSet
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be easily done with DjangoFilterBackend.

You can try and follow the steps [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

under Generic Filtering.

If that doesn't work - you can try a third-party package like `django-filters` :) Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Also look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/ under `Lookups that span relationships` and have a look at the Q object in Django :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so basically i used django-filters package as you guys adviced me, but i don't know how to achieve effect of filtering multiple times by the same single query key.

What i mean is that if someone will try to filter by few author names like this:

> ?author=tolkien&author=jan

Then how can i filter database by these two values "tolkien" and "jan"?

My filter set looks like this:

```
class BookFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    author = filters.CharFilter(field_name='authors__name' ,lookup_expr='icontains')
    categories__name = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    published_date = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['author', 'categories__name', 'published_date']
```

And view function like this:

```
class BooksView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BooksSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend,]
    filterset_class = BookFilter
```

Effect i want to achieve is getting queryset with books whose authors are persons with names containing jan, or tolkien