# How to filter query by multiple values using DRF, djagno-filters and HyperlinkedIdentityField values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

**Main target**
is to get query set based on multiple values in query.

Business logic is to get all contracts for multiple drivers.

Example:
request url:

`/api/contract/?driver=http://localhost:8000/api/driver/1,http://localhost:8000/api/driver/2`

Response should be all contracts for these two drivers.

Driver Serializer:

```
class DriverSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='driver-detail',
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = [
            'url',
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
        ]
```

Contract serializer:

```
class ContractSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='contract-detail',
        read_only=True
    )
    driver = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = [
            'url',
            'id',
            'contract_detail_fields',
            'driver',
        ]
```

Contract View

```
class ContractViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.ContractSerializer
    queryset = Contract.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = ContractFilter
```

ContractFilter:

```
class ContractFilter(FilterSet):
    driver = CustomHyperlinkedIdentityFilterList('driver')
```

What I have tried is to make custom filterField based on answer [by Sherpa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230820/14599969)

```
class CustomHyperlinkedIdentityFilterList(django_filters.BaseCSVFilter, 
                                                 django_filters.CharFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        values = value or []
        for value in values:
            qs = super(CustomHyperlinkedIdentityFilterList,
                       self).filter(qs, value)
        return qs
```

Answer is *ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'http://localhost:8000/api/drivers/driver/3/'.*

Then I am trying to modify to filter by id not urlField and changing this line

`qs = super(CustomHyperlinkedIdentityFilterList, self).filter(qs, value)`

to this:

`qs = super(CustomHyperlinkedIdentityFilterList, self).filter(qs, get_id_from_url(value))`

where get_id_from_url is:

```
def get_id_from_url(url):
    return int(resolve(urlparse(unquote(url)).path).kwargs.get('pk'))
```

But it return me only contracts for last driver, not for both.

Then I also tried configurations based on answer [by Slava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69590160/14599969)

```
class ContractFilter(FilterSet):
  
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = ['driver']
```

by using this solutions response is Bad request
*{"driver":["Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."]}*

I hope there is very simple solutions which I have missed.

Comment: I guess I found solution by modifing [Sherpa][1] answer.

`qs_values = [get_id_from_url(v) for v in values] qs_s = qs.filter(driver__in=qs_values) return qs_s`
Can someone advice me hot to get change it so I can get `driver__id` in dynamic way?

Comment: Can you not use just the driver's ID rather than a whole URL? Why would you complicate your life so much by passing drivers by link and then parsing this link in order to get their IDs with `def get_id_from_url(url)`?

Comment: @antpngl92 good point. This design by using urls as relations was before this task, I don't have answer why this design was chosen. I keep it for conviction.